# CGColor - CGColorGetComponents doesn't seem to work properly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rgb, cgcolor

I am trying to get the rgb values from a CGColor
I use the followig code. The problem is that all returned values for red, green, and blue always return as a float and they are always between 0 and 1 for example: `rgb(0.000000, 0.847059, 0.945098)`

How do i convert these val;ues to real rgb values?

```
int numComponents = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color);

if (numComponents == 4)
{
        const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color);
    CGFloat red = components[0];
    CGFloat green = components[1];
    CGFloat blue = components[2];
    CGFloat alpha = components[3];
}
```

Comment: Those *are* real RGB values. What exactly are you expecting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It returns the correct rgb values represented as a percentage. So if your Red = .8 it's 80% of 255 which is 204

so your code could look like this:

```
int numComponents = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color);

if (numComponents == 4)
{
    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color);
    NSInteger red = (NSInteger) components[0] * 255;
    NSInteger green = (NSInteger) components[1] * 255;
    NSInteger blue = (NSInteger) components[2] * 255;
    CGFloat alpha = components[3];
}
```

Comment: I do believe that is incorrect that will cast the values as an integer before the multiplication. The only 2 possible values at that point will be 0 and 255.

Comment: oo I didn't copy the code I used the idea so it worked for me

Comment: That multiplication code doesn't seem right. Due to the integer casting/truncation, only a floating-point value of *exactly* 1.0 will become 255 this way; a value of 0.999 will become 254, which is undesirable because it should be 255 also. The result shouldn't be 254 until you get all the way down to 0.996 or so. I think you want to multiply by 255.999 instead of 255. That will cause a better distribution into the integers 0 through 255.